# Pointwise and uniform convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n(1-x)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

I need to determine whether

$\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n(1-x)$

converges pointwise and/or uniformly in $\mathbb{R}$

What I tried so far:
$\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n(1-x)$ converges only if $|x| < 1$ or if $x=1$.

Does that mean that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n(1-x)$ does not converge pointwise in $\mathbb{R}$ and therefore also not uniformly?

Comment: Yes, that's right.  It's a good exercise to show convergence is uniform on $[0,1]$  or on $[a, 1]$  where $-1 < a \le 0$.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed your series diverges when $x=-1$ (for instance), and therefore, in particular, it is not an uniformly convergent series of functions from $\mathbb R$ into $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously it's
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n(1-x)=(1-x)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n$$
but $\sum_{n\geq 0}x^n$ is a well known series which converges for $|x|<1$. For $x=1$ the whole term is zero, hence it converges in $(-1,1]$. The convergence is uniform in $(a,1]$ for each $a\in (-1,1]$. But uniform convergence implies pointwise convergence.